# How to add a gesture recognizer to a view in a collection view cell?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I've been trying to set up a gesture recognizer to a view that is inside a `UICollectionViewCell` and contains three views. Every time I press on that view, the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is being invoked instead of the gesture recognizer.

Here's what I’m doing;

```
class RealTimePostCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet private var linkPreviewView: UIView!
@IBOutlet private var linkCanonicalURLLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private var linkImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet private var linkTitleLabel: UILabel!

// -------------------------------------------

fileprivate var delegate: RealTimePostDelegate!
fileprivate var contentViewModel: RealTimeContentViewModel!

// -------------------------------------------

class func create(forCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView,
                  atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath,
                  withReuseIdentifier reuseIdentifier: String,
                  andContentViewModel contentViewModel: RealTimeContentViewModel,
                  delegate: RealTimePostDelegate) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RealTimePostCollectionViewCell
    cell.setup(withContentViewModel: contentViewModel, delegate: delegate)
    
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    
    return cell
}

private func setup(withContentViewModel contentViewModel: RealTimeContentViewModel, currentUserId: String, delegate: RealTimePostDelegate) {
    setupGestureRecognizers()
}

fileprivate func setupGestureRecognizers() {
    if linkPreviewView.gestureRecognizers?.isEmpty ?? true == true {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(linkPreviewViewWasPressed))
        linkPreviewView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        linkPreviewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func linkPreviewViewWasPressed() {
    guard let link = contentViewModel.link, !link.isEmpty else { return }
    delegate.linkPreviewWasPressed(link: link)
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(linkPreviewViewWasPressed))
cell.linkPreviewView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
cell.linkPreviewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
return cell
```

Comment: That's what I’ve done, I just don’t do it directly in the View Controller.

Comment: Add added it  **cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false** ?